# Computing homomorphisms between extensions of modules

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

Suppose we have two exact sequences of $R$-modules ($R$ is a commutative ring)

$$0\rightarrow M_0\rightarrow F\rightarrow M_1\rightarrow0$$
$$0\rightarrow N_0\rightarrow G\rightarrow N_1\rightarrow0$$

such that $\text{Hom}_R(M_i, N_i)=0$, $i=1,2$. Is it possible in this case to say something about $\text{Hom}_R(F, G)$?

$\textbf{Update}$

Applying $\text{Hom}_R(-,G)$ to the first sequence we obtain the long exact sequence

$$0\rightarrow\text{Hom}_R(M_1,G)\rightarrow \text{Hom}_R(F,G)\rightarrow \text{Hom}_R(M_0,G)\rightarrow\text{Ext}_R^1(M_1,G)\rightarrow ...$$

Applying $\text{Hom}_R(M_1,-)$ to the second one I obtain

$$0\rightarrow\text{Hom}_R(M_1,N_0)\rightarrow \text{Hom}_R(M_1,G)\rightarrow \text{Hom}_R(M_1,N_1)\rightarrow\text{Ext}_R^1(M_1,N_0)\rightarrow...$$

thus $\text{Hom}_R(M_1,G)\cong \text{Hom}_R(M_1,N_0)$ and at least we have an embedding $\text{Hom}_R(M_1,N_0)\hookrightarrow\text{Hom}_R(F,G)$.

Comment: It contains a copy of $\hom_R(M_1,N_0)$, and it can be reduced to that.

Comment: @ Mariano Suárez-Alvarez Can you explain me please, how it can be done?

Comment: I'd rather you played with it for a while first.

Comment: @ Mariano Suárez-Alvarez  So the first part of your statement is easy.